# What would be the xpath expression for parsing out the 19 digit string at the end of the URL?

Tags: xml, xpath

Here's the HTML:

```
<a href="https://i3.student.gototraining.com/rt/7762640392746015488" 
         id="registrationURL" target="_blank" class=" xh-highlight">
    https://i3.student.gototraining.com/rt/7762640392746015488</a>
```

So for this URL: https://qa4.test.host.com/rt/7762640392746015488

I would like the xpath expression to return: 7762640392746015488

Thanks and much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following expression to extract the final `$n` characters from `$str`:

```
substring($str, string-length($str) - $n - 1);
```

Substituting your exact values (without knowing more about the location of the target `a`):

```
substring((//a[@id='registrationURL'])[1], 
          string-length((//a[@id='registrationURL'])[1]) - 18)
```

Output:

```
7762640392746015488
```

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. This my first post here, I had some trouble adding in the anchor tag which has an id called registrationURL. I eventually used this expression:substring(id('registrationURL')/@href,string-length('https://qa4.test.host.com')+5)

Comment: I'll update to reflect that there was code present. Didn't notice until you mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use substring-after function which can parse number of any length:

```
substring-after('https://qa4.test.host.com/rt/7762640392746015488', '/rt/')
```

Comment: If you look at my edits you'll see that that's what I originally posted. However, then I noticed that the title specifically asks for 19 characters.